# AsyncTask android

Tags: java, многопоточность, android-asynctask, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

По нажатию кнопки, должна запустится инициализация bluetooth модуля (hc-06) и одновременно с ней - анимация этой кнопки. Мне предложили использовать класс AsyncTask.

Вот код реализации интерфейса AsyncTask -

```
    class BluetoothConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.textView.setText("Подключено"); //та самая 181 строка
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        tryConnectToWatch();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Это инициализация модуля -

```
 public void tryConnectToWatch() {
    if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
        try {

            BluetoothDevice device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice("20:16:08:16:14:57");
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
            clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            clientSocket.connect();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

А вот обработчик нажатия кнопки

```
case R.id.connect:
            button.startAnimation(animation);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Подождите...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            BluetoothConnect bluetoothConnect = new BluetoothConnect();
            bluetoothConnect.execute();
```

После нажатия запускается анимация и инициализация, но вылетает исключение вот на эту строку -

```
mainActivity.textView.setText("Подключено"); //181 строка, помечена в коде выше
```

Исключение - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Помогите решить проблему. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

Так вы создали непривязанную к систему пустую активити, а не обратились к той, что сейчас на экране и работает.

Вам надо передать, например, вашу активити в класс и работать с ней.

```
class BluetoothConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    MainActivity activity;

    public BluetoothConnect(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        activity .textView.setText("Подключено"); //та самая 181 строка
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        tryConnectToWatch();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
BluetoothConnect bluetoothConnect = new BluetoothConnect(this);
bluetoothConnect.execute();
```

Comment: @Ker_Jen, дополнил ответ

Comment: Хм, я не и не додумался конструктор использовать, сейчас попробую...

Comment: Прекрасно! Все работает. Спасибо. Через 4 минуты зачту ответ